# Class reference and GC cycle in c#

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I saw some one wrote code int the following style:

```
Dictionary<string,SomeClass> dict = new Dictionary<string,SomeClass>();
...    
dict.Add(key,someClass);    
...    
dict[key] = null;    
dict.Remove(key);
```

I wonder if the `dict[key] = null;` necessary. Does that mean to inform the GC?
But that `someClass` is nowhere else referenced,
Is it redundant?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's redundant. If you're going to remove the key anyway, there's no point in changing the entry to have a null value first. It should make no difference to garbage collection anywhere.

Comment: Thanks. And if a parent class is being disposed, is it necessary to dispose its children(which are no where else referenced) before that?

Comment: @Sean: If they implement IDisposable, then yes, they should be disposed... Assuming the "parent" has assumed responsibility for their lifecycle.